# Background-image not working when CSS is in other folder

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a problem with my background images, not loading when I put my CSS file in a folder. I have used css/index.css for the CSS file and the fonts and everything is working except the background images. I also used background-image: url(../images/....jpg)for my images and it is still not loading the background images(white background). Once I use my CSS file outside a folder as index.css everything is working once I move the CSS file into folder and use css/index.css, everything is working except the backgrounds.
Any ideas ?
Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: You have to put you're project's structure to help getting a help

Answer (score 0):

Could be that you are missing the quotes on the image location url. 
`background-image: url("../images/....jpg")`

Other than that, you can re-check the location.

Comment: I did try with “ and also i didn’t move any images so they work with this directory if the css file is outside folder and I am using link index.css... once i put css/index.css the background images are not loading anymore ...